# How to Start New Activity to Switch to Different Tab?

Tags: android, email

I have Two Tabs Tab-1 and Tab-2 at bottom of the screen.
Send button is at Tab-1.
When user clicks send button,it will switch to Tab-2 but i lost view of both Tab-1 and Tab-2 which is at bottom.
What's wrong with my code ?
Below is my code:

```
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            CurrentActivity.this.Tab2Activity(myIntent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: your question is not clear. Please share your full code

Comment: didn't understand whether you are going for Tabhost or using Buttons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent activity class where the tabhost is created implement a method like the one below:

```
public void switchTab(int tab){
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(tab);
}
```

Inside of the tab that I would like to be able to switch internally to another tab I created the method below:

```
public void switchTabInActivity(int indexTabToSwitchTo){
        PARENTCLASSNAME ParentActivity;
        ParentActivity = (PARENTCLASSNAME) this.getParent();
        ParentActivity.switchTab(indexTabToSwitchTo);
}
```